# Something wrong with converting SDL surface to GL texture

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I can't find my mistake, why text has not been created? When using texture instead of text I get nothing or black background with colored points, please help

```
GLuint texture;
SDL_Surface *text = NULL;
TTF_Font *font = NULL;
SDL_Color color = {0, 0, 0};


font = TTF_OpenFont("../test.ttf", 20);
text = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, "Hello, SDL !!!", color);

glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, text->w, text->h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, text->pixels);

SDL_FreeSurface(text);
```

Comment: Why are you claiming that `text->pixels` from [`TTF_RenderText_Solid()`](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf_42.html#SEC42) contains RGB data in your `glTexImage2D()` call?

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could add is to specify texture filters, e.g.

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things you have to check first

1. is the font loaded properly? check if "font == NULL", maybe your
   font path is wrong
2. is the shader (if you use a shader) setup properly?

My guess is that you set the wrong pixel format type in **glTexImage2D** cause random color dots apear on your texture

Below is my code that load image via SDL_image for OpenGL use, I think it would be a good start to figure out what step you missed or forgot.

BTW, this code is not perfect. The types of pixel format is more than four (like index color) and I only handle some of them.

```
/*
 * object_, originalWidth_ and originalHeight_ are private variables in
 * this class, don't panic.
 */
void
Texture::Load(string filePath, GLint minMagFilter,  GLint wrapMode)              
{
    SDL_Surface* image;                                                      
    GLenum textureFormat;                                                    
    GLint bpp;              //Byte Per Pixel                                 

    /* Load image file */                                                    
    image = IMG_Load(filePath.c_str());                                      
    if (image == nullptr) {                                                  
            string msg("IMG error: ");                                       
            msg += IMG_GetError();                                           
            throw runtime_error(msg.c_str());                                
    }                                                                        

    /* Find out pixel format type */                                         
    bpp = image->format->BytesPerPixel;                                      
    if (bpp == 4) {                                                          
            if (image->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)                          
                    textureFormat = GL_RGBA;                                 
            else                                                             
                    textureFormat = GL_BGRA;                                 
    } else if (bpp == 3) {                                                   
            if (image->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)                          
                    textureFormat = GL_RGB;                                  
            else                                                             
                    textureFormat = GL_BGR;                                  
    } else {                                                                 
            string msg("IMG error: Unknow pixel format, bpp = ");            
            msg += bpp;                                                      
            throw runtime_error(msg.c_str());                                
    }                                                                        

    /* Store widht and height */                                             
    originalWidth_ = image->w;                                               
    originalHeight_ = image->h;

    /* Make OpenGL texture */                                                
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);                                                 
    glGenTextures(1, &object_);                                              
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, object_);                                   
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, minMagFilter);     
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, minMagFilter);     
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, wrapMode);             
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, wrapMode);             
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE);             
    glTexImage2D(                                                            
            GL_TEXTURE_2D,                  // texture type                  
            0,                              // level                         
            bpp,                            // internal format               
            image->w,                       // width                         
            image->h,                       // height                        
            0,                              // border                        
            textureFormat,                  // format(in this texture?)      
            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,               // data type                     
            image->pixels                   // pointer to data               
            );                                                               

    /* Clean these mess up */                                                
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);                                         
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);                                                
    SDL_FreeSurface(image);
}
```

For more information, you should check out [SDL wiki](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Surface?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryStruct%5Cb%29%7C%28SDLStructTemplate%29) or deep into it's source code to fully understand the architecture of SDL_Surface.

Comment: I tried what you say, and find out that BPP of my font surface is 1. I have no idea what I should do :-(